# fragment UI not updating when resuming Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-volley, updating

my application consists of several activities and fragments,
My main activity consists of a viewpager containing 3 android.support.v4.app Fragments, the 3 fragments are (voting,dashboard, and chating).
Here's the logic of my app:

1. User launches main activity
2. view pagers sets its current position to the first fragment (voting)
3. I start making a volley request to retrieve some data from a server
4. I implemented a callback to that request, so that upon data retrieval, I should update my fragment UI.

And everything works!

---

However, here's the problem resulting from the following sequence:

1. user launches main activity
2. server request is running but not yet finished
3. user quickly opens a new activity such as "view profile"
4. user quickly returns to main activity
5. callback is executed after server response to the request

and all functions responsible for updating UI are executed and I'm sure of that,
however the fragment UI is not updated

here's my code for the callback:

```
public void findMatchTriosCallback() {
    Log.i("Callback", "CheckingTrios");
    //If user has no match trios, EmptyGuide should be showed
    UserData.setFindingTrios(false);
    if (UserData.getMatchTrios() == null)
        showEmptyGuideView();
    else
        updateUI();
}
```

and to be clear, that log is printed in the console, and updateUI is executed, but unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: Where exactly is that callback code in your project? Is it in the activity or one of the fragments?  Where does the `updateUI()` method live, and what does it do?

Comment: @DanielNugent that callback function is inside my voting fragment (the fragment which contains the UI I need to update), updateUI() is a function setting texts to some textviews and setting images to some imageviews, a simple function..

Comment: when is the volley request triggered? as soon as you add the fragment or you press any button to start the request?

Comment: @ZachariasHadjikyprianou it's triggered as soon as I open my fragment (voting), it's called in the onCreateView, however I've a condition to not call it when a similar request is already running in the background

Comment: i think your problem is that you add/replace the original fragment that contains the request callback. You should check your activity's savedInstanceState in the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method and add/replace a new fragment only when savedInstanceState == null.